# Strategy and organization during the civil rights movement

Tags: civil-rights, resource, strategy

After watching the movies *Selma* and *Rustin*, I couldn't help but appreciate the strategic thinking and organizing that happened during the civil rights movement. What are some of the books that talk about the aspects of strategy, decision-making, diplomacy, etc. during the civil rights movement?

Comment: This isn't really about history, but about sociology, or some other field.

Comment: I see that there is some debate on meta about reference requests on this particular site. I didn't know about. I see why this question has been closed.

Comment: @Max. You are correct, and thank you for doing the research to find that.  You might be able to get the answer you want by asking about the characteristic strategic decisions made during the US Civil rights movement (and perhaps how they differed from other similar movements).  Good answers should provide references, which will get you the books you're looking for.  Would that help>

Comment: FWIW, [Freedom Summer](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7949430) is all about this. Particularly including how SNCC was organized, and the abuse training they put volunteers through before sending them into Mississippi.